# "Exotic" text representations methods?

Tags: text-mining, information-retrieval

I'm looking to the different methods of representing a text into a machine-readable format.
However, until now, I only found "Bag of Words" approachs with a lot of variations (boolean BoW, weighted BoW, Bag of Topics...).

What is troubling me is that these methods don't take context into account (some approach this goal by counting n-grams, wich seems a bit light to me).

I would like to know if other approaches are also used (I found no mentions of graph representation, for instance). Papers/books/websites presenting these methods would be a huge bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not exactly what I was looking for, [this paper](http://www.jair.org/media/2934/live-2934-4846-jair.pdf) presents a good survey on VSM.